# How to delete every two lines after 3rd lines in a file contains very large number of lines?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

---

Like
If I have :

```
1st line (keep)  
2nd line (keep)  
3rd line (keep)  
4rth lines (delete)  
5th (del)  
6th (keep)  
7nth (keep)  
8th lines  (keep)  
9th (del)  
10th (del)  
11th (keep)  
12th (keep)  
13th (keep)  
14th (del)  
15th (del)
```

etc....

Comment: increment a line counter (zero-indexed) for each line read, print when (line counter modulo 5>=3)

Comment: can you please clarify more,

Comment: the duplicate is slightly worded differently, but it is the same looked in a different way.. this question would be `print lines 1,2,3 out of each 5 lines` for ex: `seq 15 | awk 'BEGIN { a[1] a[2] a[3] }; NR % 5 in a'` and `seq 15 | sed -n 'p;n;p;n;p;n;n'`

Comment: also, the `sed` version above might be faster than the `awk` one for large files

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
awk '(NR-1)%5<3' file
```

For example:

```
$ awk '(NR-1)%5<3' file
1st line (keep)
2nd line (keep)
3rd line (keep)
6th (keep)
7nth (keep)
8th lines (keep)
11th (keep)
12th (keep)
13th (keep)
```

#### How it works

The command `(NR-1)%5<3` tells `awk` to print any line for which `(NR-1)%5<3` is true.  In `awk`, `NR` is the line number with the first line counting as `1`.  For every five lines in the file, that statement will be true for the first three.

Comment: Thank you, but I found this script will start to delete after the 3rd line which is okay, but for the next turn it will count again from the beginning where the lines order are changed and decreased by two lines so I can't delete the lines I want . any suggestion

Comment: @JaguarJom OK.  I showed in the answer the output from your sample input data.  Is that not the output that you wanted?  Or, is it that, when you run the code, you get something different?

Comment: yes actually i got different result actually,

Comment: To check, I just copied-and-pasted your input and copied-and-pasted my command and run it and I get the same result as shown in the answer.   Are you copying-and-pasting the same things?  Have you modified the code?  Are you testing the code on different input data?  Can you use pastebin.com or similar to show me exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: @JaguarJom In another comment, you hinted that your pattern is six lines long, not five, and you want to delete the last two of every six lines.  If that is the case, use `awk '(NR-1)%6<4' file`.

Comment: thank you, actually, I need to delete 2 lines every 3 lines, but using 5<3 didn't work for me, which work was 6<3 , I know it is weird but this when I used   "awk '{if((NR-1) % 6<=2){print $0}}' file"   this command,

Comment: In that case, `awk '(NR-1)%6<=2' file` should work.

Answer (score 6):

A simple command is:

```
awk '{if((NR-1) % 5<=2){print $0}}' file
```

It will only print first 3 lines in sequence of 5 lines. Because `(NR-1)%5` will give output like `0 1 2 3 4`, and first 3 lines are less than equal to 2. So it will only print them.

I have file with contents:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
6
7
8
11
12
13
```

Or as suggested in comments you can use:

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 5 <= 2' file
```

Comment: Or, with idiomatic use of `awk` syntax: `awk '(NR - 1) % 5 <= 2' file`

Comment: awk '{if((NR-1) % 5<=2){print $0}}' file
Thank you, this work very good for me but increasing 1 to line                 awk '{if((NR-1) % 6<=2){print $0}}' file

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you want something like 'Fizz-Buzz' in awk ...

```
awk '{ if (i++%5 < 3) print $0;}'
```

To show this works...

```
for x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ; do echo $x; done |
awk '{ if (i++%5 < 3) print $0;}'
```

When your file is named, 'mybigfile.csv',

```
awk '{ if (i++%5 < 3) print $0;}' < mybigfile.csv > mybigfile-123.csv
```

Comment: You could use NR, or just rely on i defaulting to zero :-) (_code golf_)

Answer (score 4):

A generic solution for masking out a particular pattern of lines from a file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The pattern is given on the command line.
pattern=$1

# The period is simply the length of the pattern.
period=${#pattern}

# Use bc to convert the binary pattern to an integer.
mask=$( printf 'ibase=2; %s\n' "$pattern" | bc )

awk -v mask="$mask" -v period="$period" '
    BEGIN { p = lshift(1, period-1) }
    and(rshift(p, (FNR-1) % period), mask)'
```

This relies on `awk` implementing the non-standard functions `and()` (bitwise AND), `rshift()` and `lshift()` (bitwise right and left shift), which both GNU `awk` and some BSD implementations of `awk` does, but not `mawk`.

This takes a *pattern*, which is a *binary number* representing both the cyclic period and what lines within each period should be kept or masked out.  A `1` means "keep" and a `0` means "delete".

For example:  The pattern of line that should be applied in your question is `11100`, which means "for each set of five lines, keep the first three and delete the others".

Using `01001000` would delete all but the 2nd and 5th lines in every 8 lines.

The `awk` program could also be written without the `BEGIN` block as

```
and(lshift(1, (period-1) - (FNR-1) % period), mask)
```

Left-shifting 1 by `(period-1) - (FNR-1) % period` positions is the same as calculating 2 to that power, but I'm using `lshift()` since `awk` does its arithmetics using floating point operations rather than in exact integer arithmetics.

Since the code relies on the binary representation of the pattern, very long patterns may not work well.

Testing:

Removing the lines you want to remove:

```
$ sh script.sh 11100 <file
1st line (keep)
2nd line (keep)
3rd line (keep)
6th (keep)
7nth (keep)
8th lines  (keep)
11th (keep)
12th (keep)
13th (keep)
```

Inverting the pattern:

```
$ sh script.sh 00011 <file
4rth lines (delete)
5th (del)
9th (del)
10th (del)
14th (del)
15th (del)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved using GNU `sed`:

```
sed '4~5,5~5d' file
```

Note that this uses a GNU-specific extension to the sed standard, and thus doesn't work with e.g. BSD sed on macOS. However, GNU sed can be installed on macOS using `brew`, after which it can be used as `gsed`. On Linux, GNU sed is the default.

This prints every line that does not fall in the fourth till fifth line of every five lines; for a clearer example: `sed '3~10,6~10d'` fill select lines 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10 of every group of 10 lines by deleting lines 3 till 6.

The top-voted answer suggests using `awk '(NR-1)%5<3'`. On my machine, on a file containing the numbers 1 till 2 million, this takes about 0.6 seconds, while the sed solution in this answer takes about 0.35 seconds. This is reasonable, since sed is in general a simpler tool, and can thus work faster than the more complicated, but more full-featured, awk.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below command  and it worked fine

```
for((i=1;i<=20;i++)); do  j=$(($i+2)); sed -n ''$i','$j'p' filename;i=$(($j+2)); done
```

output

```
1st line (keep)
2nd line (keep)
3rd line (keep)
6th (keep)
7nth (keep)
8th lines (keep)
11th (keep)
12th (keep)
13th (keep)
```

Comment: That is nice, but you have know how many lines you have in advance, and you're looping back from the beginning each round. It cannot be used on a stream, and it gets more inefficient the bigger the data gets, so since OP says the number of lines is very large, this is not the best solution.